# Split the String by number

Tags: java, string

Can anyone help me to split the string by number
Eg: "I Need 5000 points" is the string I want "5000" from that string.

I tried many ways like:

```
//split the string by RegExp:
String array = string.split(".*\\d.")
```

I am getting the output but its not what I expect

Output:

```
 array[0] = ""
 array[1]  ="points
```

Can anyone help me to find the proper solution?

Comment: don't split string but perform a RegExp search

Comment: @rebeliagamer. That's a C# question. OP is not having an issue with regex itself, but how to use it.

Comment: It should be a `String[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("I Need 5000 points");
while (matcher.find()) {            
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to split on everything that is **not** a number:

```
String array[] = string.split("\\D+");
```

Comment: it should be an array

Answer (score 1):

```
        String str="I Need 5000 points";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m=p.matcher(yourString);
    while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this one (should also work with digit numbers):

```
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", "I Need 5000 points");
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can try to split by
 `str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");  //match a number with optional '-' and decimal.`

Although this is not the way what you have tried. Get the  string[] by `myString.split("\\s+");` and then check the splitted string contains any number or not.

Be careful with the above RegEx mechanism, though, as it'll fail if your using non-latin (i.e. 0 to 9) digits. For example, arabic digits.

You can take a look here - [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

String myString = "I Need 5000 points";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
if(matcher.find())            
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```